# Kafka Avro Value deserialization issue

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I send data using the AvroSpecific or AvroGeneric method and it works fine. The problem occurs when I try to consume the data sent by the above methods.

I use version libraries:

- Confluent.Kafka **v1.4.0**
- Confluent.SchemaRegistry **v1.4.0**
- Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes **v1.3.0**

Here is my Consumer code:

```
var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig
{
    Url = schemaRegistryUrl
};

using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig))
using (var consumer =
      new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, GenericRecord>(consumerConfig)
      .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
      .Build())
{
    consumer.Subscribe(topicName);

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(token);
                //do something
            }
            catch (ConsumeException ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error occured: {ex.Error.Reason}", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        consumer.Close();
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot exception]

Comment: Are you sure no one else is pushing non-Avro data into the topic? Can you read the topic using just `kafka-avro-console-consumer`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the Kafka console. Instead, I found a solution to my problem. Changes in the library turned out to be a problem. Thank you for your attention.  [Confluent Kafka issues](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1246)

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access? You just download that command from `confluent.io` or `install confluent-platform` with brew or apt/yum (maybe chocolatey)